How to ensure a specific method is called after method chaining in C#?
I'm trying to create an API in C# that uses method chaining. I want to ensure that at the end of the chain, a specific method (e.g., Throw()) is called. If this method is not called, an exception should be thrown.
Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:
public interface IChainable
{
    IChainable Step1();
    IChainable Step2();
    void Throw();
}

public class Chainable : IChainable, IDisposable
{
    private bool _throwCalled = false;

    public IChainable Method1()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IChainable Method2()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Throw()
    {
        _throwCalled = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_throwCalled)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Throw() method must be called when finishing the chaining");
        }
    }
}

However, I want to avoid this because it requires opening a using block, which is not desired in this case:
using (var chainable = new Chainable())
{
    chainable.Step1().Step2();
    // chainable.Throw(); // If the user forgets to call Throw(), an exception is thrown when the using block ends
}

I'm looking for a more robust and deterministic way to ensure that Throw() is called at the end of the chain, without having to use a using block. Is there any technique or pattern that can help me implement this more efficiently?
Any help is appreciated!

Why is using not desired? Is it just because people can choose not to write a using block? Or is it that you don't want to require people to write anything extra? Also, are people allowed to store a IChainable in a local variable first, then eventually call Throw on that? For example: var temp = chainable.Step1().Step2(); then at some other point, temp.Throw();

I also suspect that this is an XY problem. Please explain what the purpose of this API is. Perhaps method chaining is not suitable here, and perhaps there is a way to implement this without forcing people to call Throw in the first place.

Sure, the using block would be undesirable because it's extra code. I thought of using chaining because I'm considering a guard approach, where I intend to accumulate errors and return them all at once instead of throwing them at the first error found. Chaining seems, in my opinion, cleaner than accumulating errors separately. The Throw method, in this case, would be a way to prevent validated fields from being used improperly or someone forgetting to throw the exception.

Runtime errors are a poor way to handle this. Related compiler discussion https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34098 which references https://github.com/mykolav/must-use-ret-val-fs

It would seem like renaming Throw as Dispose would do most of what you want - there's plenty of tooling that already tells you that you've forgotten to dispose of disposables and now you write using instead of Throw() so it's not even much change in character count.

using isn't extra code, it's what guarantees safe and deterministc disposal, cancellation/whatever. There are several features in all languages. It's far more important than chaining which, in the end, is little more than styling. Chaining is not the same as pipelining, although it's often use to emulate it

If you want a functional interface why not look at F#? Right now you're trying to emulate functional code, but concentrating on the wrong concepts. Handling failure in a pipeline of function calls is often done using Railway oriented programming concepts, ensuring that either problems don't even compiler or are explicitly handled. If the response of the pipeline is such that only Throw() (bad name) can produce it, forgetting to call it won't even compile

@PanagiotisKanavos You're correct about the using block, but what I meant is that I didn't intend to use it. I wanted to know if there was a way to achieve the same idea, so the user couldn't omit the method I intended them to call at the end of the chain. And you're also right that Throw is a bad name for this, but it was just for example. And I have never used F#.

@AndreyNamikaze do read about F# and functional programming then, because that's what you're trying to emulate, in a very roundabout way.  LINQ ensures people don't mix up operators by having operators like OrderBy return a different type (IOrderedEnumerable) that only allows specific operations. In your case, instead of void have all methods, including the last, return something. Have the last method return eg IEnd or ICompletePipeline and assign that to a field or variable of the same type. This way the compiler will throw an error if a call is missed.

@AndreyNamikaze the other trick is that what you specify is actually a pipeline of calls, not just calls made one after the other. C# already allows you to specify functions as data through Func<>, no interfaces are needed. That's how LINQ works. If, instead of interfaces, you use Func's piped together, the compiler itself will verity that the pipeline input and outputs are those you specified. It's easier in F# but libraries like this one allow the same style

It you're looking for fluent design, check this out https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/fluent-interface-design-pattern/
In this case you can add your method like
someType = obj.Do1().Do2().Throw();
if (someType.thrown)
    DoSome();

But this does not really solve your issue. Chain responsibility could. Here is an idea in pseudo code

abstract class HandlerBase 
{
    public HandlerBase NextH {get;set;}
    public bool Throws {get;set;}
   
    public abstract bool Handle();
    
    protected void ThrowPrivate(bool mustThrow)
    {
         if (mustThrow && Throws)
             throw new Exception("");
    }
}


class Handler1 : HandlerBase 
{
    public Handler1(HandlerBase nextH, bool throws)
    {
        NextH = nextH;
        Throws = throws;
    }

    public override bool Handle()
    {
        DoSomething1();
        bool success =  NextH.Handle() ?? true;
        base.ThrowPrivate(!success);
        return success;
    }
}

class Handler2 : HandlerBase 
{
    public Handler2(HandlerBase nextH, bool throws)
    {
        NextH = nextH;
        Throws = throws;
    }

    public override bool Handle()
    {
        DoSomething2();
        bool success = NextH?.Handle() ?? true;
        base.ThrowPrivate(!success);
        return success;
    }
}

var hnd = new Handle1(new Handle2(null, false), true);
hnd.Handle();

in this case, unless you reach the end and executed whatever last handler you have, you will get exception. This code can be improved to make base class do more work. Also, this is a deviation from the classic chain of responsibility design. It can be composed differently.

Based on your comment of how you want to use this:

The Throw method, in this case, would be a way to prevent validated
fields from being used improperly or someone forgetting to throw the
exception.

First solution:
We can make the fields accessible only as properties via reference of a new interface IValidatedChainable that Throw (or renamed Validate in my code) would be returning. The concrete class that implements IValidatedChainable can be a private nested class of Chainable so that nothing but us can instantiate it.
Complete example:
public interface IChainable {
    IChainable Step1();
    IChainable Step2();
    IValidatedChainable Validate();
}

public interface IValidatedChainable {
    public int ValidatedField { get; }
}

public class Chainable : IChainable {

    private class Validated : IValidatedChainable {
        public int ValidatedField => 42;
        
        Chainable _validated;
        public Validated(Chainable validated) {
            _validated = validated;
        }
    }

    public IChainable Step1() {
        return this;
    }

    public IChainable Step2() {
        return this;
    }

    public IValidatedChainable Validate() {
        // throw errors
        return new Validated(this);
    }
}

Then usage is:
// intended use
var validated = new Chainable()
               .Step1()
               .Step2()
               .Validate();
Console.WriteLine(validated.ValidatedField); // 42

// unintended use - compile time check
var chainable = new Chainable();
chainable
    .Step1()
    .Step2();
//Console.WriteLine(chainable.ValidatedField); // compile time error
var validatedChainable = chainable.Validate(); // could throw
Console.WriteLine(validatedChainable.ValidatedField); // 42

Second Solution
Have the chaining methods be facades for registering private methods to a delegate chain that is invoked by Validate. To signal that we are in a possibly inconsistent state (having non-null chain) , we need to implement guarding logic in all properties/public methods to throw exceptions that Validate hasn't been called.
public interface IChainable
{
    IChainable Step1(int fieldValue);
    IChainable Step2();
    IChainable Validate();
}


public class Chainable : IChainable
{
    private delegate void Chain();

    Chain _chain = null;
    int _field;
    public int Field
    {
        get
        {
            // something smarter than that but to this point
            if (_chain != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Please call Validate");
            }
            return _field;
        }
        set
        {
            // something smarter than that but to this point
            if (_chain != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Please call Validate");
            }
            _field = value;
        }
    }

    public IChainable Step1(int fieldValue)
    {
        _chain += () => Step1Internal(fieldValue);
        return this;
    }

    private void Step1Internal(int fieldValue)
    {
        _field = fieldValue;
        // logic of Step1
    }

    public IChainable Step2()
    {
        _chain += Step2Internal;
        return this;
    }

    private void Step2Internal()
    {
        if (_field < 10)
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid field value");
        }
    }

    public IChainable Validate()
    {
        var aggregateException = new AggregateException();
        if (_chain == null) return this;

        Delegate[] delegateChain = _chain.GetInvocationList();

        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (Chain del in delegateChain)
        {
            try
            {
                del();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }

        if (exceptions.Count > 0)
        {
            _chain = null;
            throw new AggregateException(
    "Encountered errors while trying to do something.",
    exceptions
);
        }

        _chain = null;
        return this;
    }
}

Use:
var chainable = new Chainable();
var input = 42;

chainable
.Step1(input)
.Step2();

//Console.WriteLine(chainable.Field); // Exception -> Please call validate

try
{
    chainable.Validate();
    Console.WriteLine(chainable.Field); // 42

}
catch (AggregateException ex) // if input < 10
{
    
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault().Message);
}

Third solution:
Implement custom analyzers similar to how xUnit is working giving warnings that the API is misued.

Thank you for responding. I thought of something like this, but there's no way to guarantee that the user won't use a variable of type var and hide the error.
var finishedChainable = new Chainable()
.Step1()
.Step2();

@AndreyNamikaze see updated code. Not super pretty, but I think it provides guarantees that the user can't circumvent as easily as forgetting a using statement

Well, this still doesn't even warn the user that they forgot to call the correct method:
var finishedChainable = new Chainable()
.Step1()
.Step2();
Anyway, I renamed the methods. I think it will be less confusing, as I expected the user to also be able to do:
var finishedChainable = new Chainable()
.Step1()
.Throw();

@AndreyNamikaze the point is that they won't be able to use anything if they didn't call Validate as it returns an interface that exposes only validated functionality that's not available otherwise. Now if you expose properties from a reference of the Chainable class that obv won't work.

alternatively, you can just use a custom analyzer to emit such warnings..

I'll think more about this problem. Maybe I'm just overcomplicating things.

@AndreyNamikaze maybe. I have another solution that I can write up if you think it will work. Use a MultiCastDelegate to build a chain of method calls. Each Step* will register a delegate to the chain and return this. Then in throw you can walk the chain, catch exceptions etc. If the delegate is not null, any user facing code will throw an exception that potentially the object is in a potentially invalid state and call Throw to check for unobserved errors.

I'm concerned about the complexity this would bring, especially because I plan to add many methods for different value validations.

@AndreyNamikaze what you want to achieve isn't simple, so its solution is bound to be more or less complex. Your using approach is not the most fool-proof since nothing prevents the user from using the object in its invalid state BEFORE exiting the using block. In my solutions it's either impossible at compile time to use or the user gets an exception at runtime. With the delegate approach the chained methods don't even fire before Validate is called. You can also reconsider how you want to do this, I am just trying to answer given original constraints / question.

If I may suggest to the Finally block of Try-Catch-Finally block.
Regardless of the code execution getting into try or catch, you will always triggers the "Finally" block.


bool done = false;
try
{
   // some code here
   done = true;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   // some code here
   done = true;
}
finally
{
  // check if done is true?
}



Hope this helps.

Well, that isn't what I need. But thank you.

You can use state patterns to ensure certain methods can only be called after specific states.
public class Process
{
    private enum State { Start, Step1Completed, Step2Completed, FinalStepCompleted }
private State currentState = State.Start;

public Process Step1()
{
    if (currentState != State.Start)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid state for Step1.");

    currentState = State.Step1Completed;
    // Step1 logic
    return this;
}

public Process Step2()
{
    if (currentState != State.Step1Completed)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid state for Step2.");

    currentState = State.Step2Completed;
    // Step2 logic
    return this;
}

public Process FinalStep()
{
    if (currentState != State.Step2Completed)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid state for FinalStep.");

    currentState = State.FinalStepCompleted;
    // Final step logic
    return this;
}

}
// Usage
var process = new Process();
process.Step1()
       .Step2()
       .FinalStep();


That's not exactly what I need, because the previous methods don't need to be called to move to the next one, as something like this should also be valid:
var finishedChainable = new Chainable()
.Step1()
.Throw();
But thank you for responding.
